# Big $O$ and small $o$ notations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods

$a)$ Determine for all pairs $i$ and $j$, $i,j ∈ \{1, \ldots, 6\}$ whether for the ones given below functions $f_i ∈ O(f_j)$ or $f_i ∈ o(f_j)$ or neither of the two applies as $n → \infty$:

$f_1 = \log(n),$

$f_2 = \log(\sqrt n),$

$f_3 = \log(n + \log(n)),$

$f_4 = \sqrt{\log(n)},$

$f_5 = \log\log(n^{\log(n)}),$

$f_6 = \log_2(n)$

$b)$ Show that for the functions $ f(n) = \log(n!) $ and $g(n) = n\log(n)$ it holds that
$f ∈ O(g)$ and $g ∈ O(f)$. In fact, $f$ and $g$ are even asymptotically equivalent.

I am confused about the big $O$ and small $o$. When is $f_{i} ∈ O(f_j)$ and when is $f_i ∈ o(f_j)$? How to prove asymptotic equivalence?

Comment: Here are the definitions of [$O$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) and [$o$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). Note that $o(f)\subseteq O(f)$ (in fact, $o(f)\subsetneq O(f)$ if $f\not\equiv0$). To prove $\log n!\sim n\log n$, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is more than enough.

Comment: A useful special case in your Q is that if $0\ne L=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n)$ then $f\in O(g)$ and $g\in O(f)$ and neither is in $o$ of the other. It is also common to write $p=O(q)$ or $p=o(q).$ And if you see $O(p)$ or $o(p)$ as part of a formula, e.g. $\sqrt {n^2+1}=n+O(1/n^2)=n+o(1/n)$, it means some function which belongs to the set $O(p)$ or the set $o(p).$

Answer (score 2):

$f_{1,2,3,6}$ are all big-oh of each other

- they are essentially within a constant of each other.

$f_4$ is little-oh of those since they go to infinity and this is the square root of it.

$f_5
=\log(\log(n)\log(n))
=\log(\log(n))+\log(\log(n))
=2\log(\log(n))
$
is little-oh of all of the above since
$ \log (n) = o(n)$.